# Getting every returned value of a recursive procedure

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I want to assign the return value of a recursive function to a variable during recursion. I'm trying to implement recursive random number generator and I want to save each value returned by the procedure before it stops. Don't know how.

```js
function rand(seed, m, inc, mod)
{
    if(seed === 0)
        return 2;
    else
        return (m * rand(seed-1, m, inc, m) + inc) % mod;
}
```

Comment: do you have a call of the function and the wanted result with and without saved values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need some bucket to store the values in.

```
function rand(depth, m, inc, mod, bucket=[]) {
  let nextStep = 2;

  if(depth !== 0) {
    nextStep = (m * rand(depth-1, m, inc, m, bucket) + inc) % mod;
  }

  bucket.push(nextStep);
  return bucket;
}

// somewhere else
const generatedRandomValues = rand(a, b, c, d);
const randomValue = generatedRandomValues[-1];
```

ps. consider using intermediate variables to make the intention of the code more clear (like telling a story)